# Java Regex: replace any B between A and Z

Tags: java, regex

Assuming this input String:

```
A-B-C-B-Z
```

I'm trying to **replace any `B` between `A`and `Z`**.

The following Regex only matches the last occurrence of `B`:

```
(.*A.*)B(.*Z.*)
```

...when replacing (`Pattern.replaceAll()`) with `$1-$2` the result is

```
A-B-C---Z
```

The expected result would be

```
A---C---Z
```

instead.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You've to follow iterative approach.

Comment: @RohitJain you mean really iterating, buffering, state remembering and replacing directly with Java code, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can use lookarounds like this:

```
String str = "F-B-P-B-A-B-C-B-Z-D-B-A-B-C-B-Z-C";
String repl = str.replaceAll("(?<=A.{0,999})B(?=((?!A|Z).)*Z)", "-");
//=> F-B-P-B-A---C---Z-D-B-A---C---Z-C
```

As per your comment you can use this regex:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll(
  "(?<=<!\\[CDATA\\[.{0,999})&amp;(?=((?!<!\\[CDATA\\[|\\]\\]>).)*\\]\\]>)", "-");
```

Caveat is that this is assuming your input is up to 999 in length.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. Looks promising, but fails with multiple `A..B..Z` sequences within the same string, e.g. `F-B-P-B-A-B-C-B-Z-D-B-A-B-C-B-Z-C` transforms to `F-B-P-B-A---C---Z-D---A---C---Z-C` while it should be `F-B-P-B-A---C---Z-D-B-A---C---Z-C`. Can look-behind stop when Z is found?
Note that I'm of course not really using `A`, `B` and `Z`. What I'm really doing is replacing `&amp;`s (= `B`) in CDATA sections, hence `<![CDATA[` (= `A`) and `]]>` (= `Z`)...

Comment: I suggest you provide some examples like this in question so that I can suggest you better regex solution.

Comment: I have updated my answer for the problem in question and also I tried to guess a regex for the problem you added in comments. Check updated one.

Comment: Thanks very much, works perfectly now! ...admitted that I've no clue how this works/what's the implementation idea. Some hints on reading on about the used concepts would be perfect++.
Another thing: what's the performance impact of `{0,999}`? My string are probably much longer. Do you think `{0,10000000}` will take performance to zero?

Comment: do you think "Java Regex: replace any B between A and Z." would be more appropriate for this question?

Comment: Yes I agree that will be a better title.

Comment: What about the exact opposite: "replace any B not between A and Z"?

Comment: Change `?=` to `?!` above but please don't add new questions from comments as it is not encouraged on SO. Better to create a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72274/discussion-between-viviansteller-and-anubhava).

Comment: Read on under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865704/java-regex-replace-any-b-not-between-a-and-z