# Java Regex: replace any B NOT between A and Z

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that replaces any `B` in a string that is not surrounded by `A` and `Z`.
Note that there may be many `B`s inside and outside of sequences starting with `A` and ending `Z`, but I only want to replace those that are outside.

In other words: what Regex is required to make the following JUnit test pass?

```
@Test
public void testReplaceBnotBetweenAandZ() throws Exception {
    String str = "U-B-V-B-A-B-C-B-Z-W-A-B-Z-B-U";
    String repl = str.replaceAll(**#REGEX#**, "x");

    Assert.assertEquals("U-x-V-x-A-B-C-B-Z-W-A-B-Z-x-U", repl);
}
```

The real use case is to replace any `&` characters of an (X)HTML string that are not contained in a CDATA section. (`B` = `&`, `A` = `<![CDATA[` and `Z` = `]]>`).

Thanks!

Comment: Should B in `A-C-B-D-Z` be replaced?

Comment: @Pshemo No, `B` in `A-C-B-D-Z` shouldn't be replaced as it is surrounded by `A` and `Z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **negative lookahead**:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("(?<!A[^AZ]{0,999})B(?![^AZ]*Z)", "x");
//=> U-x-V-x-A-B-C-B-Z-W-A-B-Z-x-U
```

Comment: This regex will get more complicated for `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`

Comment: Thanks, but same goes here: difficult to translate this to the 'real world' use case with `&`s in CDATAs...  
Moreover I'd favor @davide's solution because his solution works without an explicit boundary and is little bit more readable.

Comment: [Except that that solution doesn't even work](https://regex101.com/r/zE4dG4/1) Do you seriously believe I wouldn't have suggested such a simple solution to you on chat itself?

Comment: Interestingly, in Java this really works: http://fiddle.re/p6yan6. The given test passes with @davide's regex. PCRE seems to treat something different here...  
And well, no, probably this is really a tough use case for Regex, I just wasn't aware that this is something that difficult. But I'm getting to believe this ;-)

Comment: My solution is not general enough, just works on your test string. I think that this is the solution that should be accepted.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it really solves the question although not solving the use case behind it. According to other commenters, this is the more generic solution.

Comment: As I suggested above regex solution with `CDATA` is pretty nasty. In case you still need it: **`str.replaceAll("(?<!<!\\[CDATA\\[((?!(<!\\[CDATA\\[|\\]\\]>)).){0,999})B(?!((?!(<!\\[CDATA\\[|\\]\\]>)).)*\\]\\]>)", "x")`**

Comment: Hm, I can't confirm this. The 'nasty regex' doesn't match anything?

Comment: @viviansteller: This answer only checks up to a thousand characters in front to make sure that it can't find `A[^AZ]*` preceding B. If it spans more than that many characters, it will return the wrong result. Of course, the limit can be increased, but look-behind in Java is quite inefficient, since it will start checking from index - min, index - min - 1, ... to index - max, where min and max are the minimum length and maximum length of the strings that can be matched by the pattern inside the look-behind.

Comment: Hrs regex is not the best tool for this job.

Answer (score 1):

The boundless, quickest way is to match both *A - Z* and *B*
Then replace appropriately within a callback.

Find:  `(A[^Z]*Z)|B`
Replace Callback: Group 1 matched ? Group 1 : "x"

```
   ( A [^Z]* Z )                # (1)
|  B
```

Sample code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(A[^Z]*Z)|B");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {
    if (m.start(1) < 0) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "x");
    } else {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "$1");
    }
}

m.appendTail(sb);
```

For your actual use case:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\Q<![CDATA[\\E(?:(?!\\Q]]>\\E).)*\\Q]]>\\E)|&");
```

Comment: @nhahtdh - Just found Java has no replace callback and its done as you specify. _thanks_

Comment: I think they will be added in Java 9. There is a feature request and progress in stream and lambdafication of Matcher class.

Answer (score 0):

`/(?<!A-)B(?!-Z)/` passes the test.

```
 @Test
 public void testReplaceBnotBetweenAandZ() throws Exception {
    String str = "U-B-V-B-A-B-C-B-Z-W-A-B-Z-B-U";
    String repl = str.replaceAll("(?<!A-)B(?!-Z)", "x");

    Assert.assertEquals("U-x-V-x-A-B-C-B-Z-W-A-B-Z-x-U", repl);
 }
```

I used negative lookahead `(?!-Z)` and lookbehind `(?<!A-)`. You can find [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) more about.

Comment: though this regex solve the question, it doesn't seem to solve the real use case(however the real use case doesn't seem to be a good practice for regex).

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr  why's the real use case not a good one for regex? what would be a more appropriate solution?

Comment: @viviansteller because regex doesn't count occurrence. have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma. your real use case is `CFG`, or `context free gramma`, so you simply can't. you need to use a formalized package for this.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr is right, while the suggested answer passes the test, it doesn't do so for the real use case with `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`, but I think I syntactical issues here...

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr to be honest, `CFG`s and Lemmas are not my strengths ;-) I'm simply trying to solve a 'real world' problem. Maybe better to go with reading byte by byte, buffering and replacing iteratively then?

Comment: @viviansteller if you just want a practice, it would be very easy. there are 4 sections in the string: `<![CDATA[`, `]]>`, inside of CDATA, any where else. char by char is a perfect way to solve this.

Comment: Is a bit fishy to use a regex for such a task. They cannot handle nested structures, and the fact that a lookbehind cannot handle infinite repetition, i.e. `*` and `+`, further complicate the issue.

Comment: @anubhava If you change the test string, of course it does not work.

Comment: Test string is exactly as per the question that is **replace any B NOT between A and Z**

Comment: Ok fine, I got your point. In any case, I wrote that it passes the test, and it passes it.